# How should I use nodejs visit thrift TNonblockingServer or to communicate with TNonblockingSocket

Tags: java, node.js, thrift

I'm trying to use thrift to relalize communication between nodejs client and Java server

Thrift offer different kinds of java server which have been implemented
· TSimpleServer
· TNonblockingServer
· THsHaServer
· TThreadedSelectorServer
· TThreadPoolServer

I have successfully used nodejs client to call the function in TTSimpleServer and TThreadPoolServer which both use TServerSocket to initialize

```
TServerSocket serverTransport = new TServerSocket(9090);

CalculatorService.Processor<CalculatorImpl> processor = new CalculatorService.Processor<CalculatorImpl>(
                    new CalculatorImpl());

            TThreadPoolServer.Args args = new TThreadPoolServer.Args(serverTransport).processor(processor);
            args.maxWorkerThreads(100);

            TServer server = new TThreadPoolServer(new TThreadPoolServer.Args(
                    serverTransport).processor(processor));

            System.out.println("Starting server on port 9090 ...");
            server.serve();
```

but when I try to use TNonblockingServer,TThreadedSelectorServer and THaHsServer ,  I came acrross following error in nodejs client

> ```
> { [Error: read ECONNRESET] code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' }
> ```

I realized that this may be caused by TNonblockingSocket, is there any method to use nodejs communicate with TNonblockingSocket

```
try
        {
            TNonblockingServerTransport serverTransport = new TNonblockingServerSocket(
                    9090);

            CalculatorService.Processor<CalculatorImpl> processor = new CalculatorService.Processor<CalculatorImpl>(
                    new CalculatorImpl());

            TServer server = new TThreadedSelectorServer(new TThreadedSelectorServer.Args(
                    serverTransport).processor(processor));
            System.out.println("Starting server on port 9090 ...");
            server.serve();
        } catch (TTransportException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

my nodejs client code is as follow

```
 var thrift = require('thrift');

var ThriftTransports = require('thrift/transport');
var ThriftProtocols = require('thrift/protocol');
var Calculator = require('./gen-nodejs/CalculatorService.js');
var ttypes = require('./gen-nodejs/tutorial_types');

transport = ThriftTransports.TFramedTransport();
protocol = ThriftProtocols.TBinaryProtocol();

var connection = thrift.createConnection("localhost", 9090, {
  transport : transport,
  protocol : protocol
});

connection.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log(err)
});

// Create a Calculator client with the connection
var client = thrift.createClient(Calculator, connection);

client.send_print(1,1, function(err, response) {
      console.log("send_print result:" + response);
    });
```

Comment: A typical issue is that certain server types implicitly expect the client to use `TFramedTransport`. Have you checked that?

Comment: `transport = ThriftTransports.TFramedTransport()` @JensG

Comment: i used this transport in line 8 in my node.js code @JensG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well , I just found the answer 
This problem is truly caused by TTFramedTransport
i found even when I use this in my code

```
transport = ThriftTransports.TFramedTransport();
```

the transport seems not successfully been assigned TFramedTransport

I just try  this way

```
transport = require('./node_modules/thrift/framed_transport.js')
```

it succeeded

I am not familiar with node.js , maybe I figure out why this happen later